# Расшифровать код - задание на собеседовании

Tags: c++, задание-на-собеседовании

Необходимо объяснить, что происходит в этой строке кода

```
<:&:>(...)->/*:*/void<:<::>:><%!&R";(%\');"<:-0:>||~0|0,0.;%>(U"%:"[0]);
```

Comment: Что за контора выдает такие ребусы?

Comment: Сразу такую контору посылать прямым текстом. У них нет будущего. Люди, которые пишут невнятный, неподдерживаемый код, не выживут на рынке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменив диграфы и устранив комментарий получим

```
[&](...) -> void [[]] { !&R";(%\');"[-0] || ~0 | 0, 0.; } (U"%:"[0]);
```

Убираем `[[]]` - это пустой список атрибутов функции, который "ничего не делает". Убираем унарный `-` перед `0`

```
[&](...) -> void { !&R";(%\');"[0] || ~0 | 0, 0.; } (U"%:"[0]);
```

Это лямбда-выражение, которое сразу же вызывается с аргументом `U"%:"[0]`. `R";(...);"` и `U"..."` - это просто формы строковых литералов в современном C++.

На этом можно остановиться. Тело функции и аргумент - формально корректные, но "бессмысленные" выражения, которые "ничего не делают".

В данном случае интересным элементом является значение `R";(%\');"[0]`, т.к. для его правильного определения надо знать синтаксис raw-литералов в С++. Однако в данной постановке задачи это значение ни на что не влияет.

P.S. Никакой ценности в качестве "задания на собеседовании" подобные ребусы не несут.

Comment: почему не несут?) А вдруг предыдущий разраб перед коммитом весь код в такой вид привёл?) Потому что ему недоплатили)

Comment: Расследование классное. Согласен с главным в P. S. ценности в задании  ноль